# Problem with the parametrisation of this surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, parametrization

I am facing troubles in understanding (read: "guessing") the correct way to parametrise this integral:

$$\int_{\Sigma} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2 + y^2}}\ \text{d}\sigma$$

Where $\Sigma = \{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3; x^2 + y^2 \leq 1; z = \sin^2(x^2+y^2)\}$

Is there a cool simple way to solve this?

I thought about the usual polar coordinated but it becomes rather strange.

Thank you!

**Idea**

Maybe it's going to be a real malarkey but I thought again about polar/cylindrical:

$$x = R\cos\theta$$
$$y = R\sin\theta$$
$$z = \sin^2(R^2)$$

Yet the ranges would become
$$R\in(-1, 1) ~~~~~~~ \theta \in (0, 2\pi) ~~~~~~~ z\in (0, 1)$$

Hence

$$\int_0^1 \text{d}z \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+R^2}}\ \text{d}R \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d}\theta = 4\pi\text{arcsinh}(1)$$

Yes/no?

Comment: $R$ need only range from $0$ to $1$ if $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$. If this is indeed a volume integral, you should reconsider the inclusion of "surface integral" in both title and tags.

Comment: Take a look at my comment in your current accepted answer. Is $\Sigma$ a surface (i.e is it exactly as you wrote down in your question?) or is it a volume (in which case, did you mean to write $0 \leq z \leq \sin^2(r^2)$)? If you intend for $\Sigma$ to mean a surface then the current accepted answer is incorrect, so please clarify which you intend.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The exercise is exactly written as I wrote here. There is no interval for $z$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your miscalculating the integration limits of $z$. If you consider the change of coordinates $x = R\cos(\varphi)$, $y = R\sin(\varphi)$ and $z = z$, then the determinant of the corresponding Jacobian matrix is given by

\begin{align*}
|J| =
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos(\varphi) & -R\sin(\varphi) & 0\\
\sin(\varphi) & R\cos(\varphi) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = R\cos^{2}(\varphi) + R\sin^{2}(\varphi) = R
\end{align*}

Therefore we get that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Sigma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm{d}\sigma = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sin^{2}(R^{2})}\frac{R}{\sqrt{1+R^{2}}}\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}\varphi\mathrm{d}R
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

**EDIT**

Let us consider the parametrization of $\Sigma$: $\displaystyle\sigma(u,v) = (u,v,\sin^{2}(u^{2}+v^{2})) = \left(u,v,\frac{1-\cos(2u^{2}+2v^{2})}{2}\right)$ whose domain is $D = \{(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1\}$. Then its partial derivatives are given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\sigma_{u} = (1,0,2u\sin(2u^{2}+2v^{2}))\\\\
\sigma_{v} = (0,1,2v\sin(2u^{2}+2v^{2}))
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then we obtain the following integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Sigma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm{d}\sigma & = \int_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^{2}+v^{2}}}\left\|\sigma_{u}\times\sigma_{v}\right\|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v\\\\
& = \int_{D}\frac{\sqrt{1 + 4(u^{2}+v^{2})\sin^{2}(2u^{2}+2v^{2})}}{\sqrt{1+u^{2}+v^{2}}}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}

Comment: It really does help! The problem is that now it's not calculable.. I mean it comes out

$$\int_0^1 \frac{R}{\sqrt{1 + R^2}} \sin^2(R^2)\ \text{d}R$$

Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Wolfram gives the following result: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+rsin%5E2%28r%5E2%29%2Fsqrt%281%2Br%5E2%29

Comment: Thank you so much! So apparently the professor went too far :D

Comment: This is incorrect. $\Sigma$ is a $2D$ surface not a $3D$ volume (based on what OP wrote), because $z= \sin^2(r^2)$, not $0\leq z \leq \sin^2(r^2)$. So, you have to express the surface measure $d\sigma$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$, and this is not simply the Jacobian (in fact the Jacobian doesn't even make sense because we're mapping $\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Indeed, you are right. But I've assumed the OP is interested in the volume corresponding to $\{(x,y,z)\in\textbf{R}^{3}:(x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1)\wedge(0\leq z\leq\sin^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}))\}$. Maybe I should have asked him in which case he is interested.

Comment: It's only $z = \sin^2(x^2++y^2)$, the professor wrote this.

Comment: I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry for having created such confusion

Comment: +1 after the edit (at this point, because of the rotational symmetry between $u,v$, we can do a usual polar coordinate transformation in the plane $u=r\cos\theta, v = r \sin \theta$ with $0<r<1$ and $0< \theta < 2\pi$... but this still leaves a pretty messy integral: $2\pi \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4r^2 \sin^2(2r^2)}}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}r\, dr$)

Comment: Thank you again! It's rather messy, but I think that I will point him this out and see what he will tell me.